# Express app.get() code in server not updating but other server code will update

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a node js and express server I run on localhost. Recently, while changing the server code from

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

to

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('home');
});
```

The server still serves the "index.html" file and does not send the message "home". I also tried deleting all my "app.get()" and "app.post()" functions and it still runs as it was before the changes. I have double checked that I saved the file and restarted the server but even then, still does the same thing. The odd thing is that when changing anything else in the server code aside from my express code it runs as expected.

I tried searching my problem but no one is experiencing the same issues. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Where's the rest of your code that defines your routes/use? And what URL do you actually use? And also, which templating engine are you using? You question's missing some important details, please edit your post and add those in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your code is not listed, so this is an educated guess, but I would check to see if you are using `express.static` or another package to serve the directory your index.html file is in via `app.use()` before your routes. By default express.static will serve index.html if presented a root path ('/').

Comment: I see you accepted this, for additional information, if you want to still use express.static but override the root path, you can add the option `index: false` to it's constructor. If there's a different path you want to override you can declare that route earlier in the file  than your `app.use(express.static(xxx))`